# Agrupar cadenas por fecha utilizando Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

estoy trabajando en un programa, y necesito agrupar cadenas de texto que están generadas en una fecha determinada.

La forma de agrupación que quiero es agrupar una misma cadena todas las veces que se repita, siempre y cuando una próxima repetición ocurra en menos de 30 días. En el caso que después de 30 días vuelva a repetirse volver a contar (es un contéo móvil).

Hasta hora estoy leyendo desde un CSV y tengo las cadenas separadas y las fechas convertidas en date, de la siguiente forma:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import numpy
    import csv
    from numpy import genfromtxt
    import numpy as np
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    from time import time

    df = pd.read_csv('Export.csv', header=0, sep=';')

    FDE=[]


    FDE=df["#"] +"-"+df["Text"]                          #Crear lista
    df[" Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df[" Date"])            #Convertir fechas a date


    print(FDE)
```

FDE es la cadena que debo buscar, cada vez que FDE se repite y la fecha asociada al FDE repetido es menor a 30 días, se debe contar. En los casos que FDE sea mayor a 30 días se debe reiniciar el conteo. De esta forma quedan distintas historias para un tipo de FDE.

El archivo del cual estoy leyendo es el siguiente:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B11sJdX_AaJBVVpZZnNDT3o4XzQ/view?usp=sharing

Cualquier idea o ayuda se agradece.

Ejemplo de salida:

```
    CCB-HYD PUPRI R = 2
    CBH-G AIR = 2
    CBD-FD AIL = 2
    CBD-FFAIL = 2
```

Saludos!

Comment: Jorge creo entender el problema, dos dudas: la fecha a la que te refieres es la de la columna `Report Date`, `FDE Date` o `Mesaje Time/Date`? Por otro lado, con lo de si el periodo repetido es menor a 30 dias te refieres desde la primera fecha del grupo o que el grupo se rompe cuando la siguiente coincidencia es posterior a 30 dias a la anterior coincidencia (no a la primera del grupo, sino a la que la precede)? Si puedes, aportar el resultado esperado del ejemplo que das sería de mucha ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: @FJSevilla La fecha es "FDE Date", para cada tipo de "FDE Text". Lo que dices es lo correcto, el grupo se rompe o historia se rompe cuando la siguiente coincidencia es posterior a 30 días. En ese momento se pueden generar otros grupos. Añadiré un ejemplo.

Comment: Añadí un ejemplo @FJSevilla por ejemplo "CCBBD-FD DOOR LOCK FAIL" tiene 2 historias, una en un junio luego 2 en noviembre, ya que la última de junio tiene una diferencia mayor a 30 días cuando sucede la siguiente la en noviembre. Espero haber aclarado tu duda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo siguiente creo que hace lo que quieres. No he encontrado una funcionalidad mágica de [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) que permita hacerlo de forma más directa. Igual existe pero la desconozco:

```
import datetime as dt

import pandas as pd

# funciones de ayuda
dateparser = lambda d: dt.datetime.strptime(d, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")

def agrupa(data):
    groups = [1]
    delta = pd.Timedelta(days=30)
    for i in range(1,len(data)):
        d1 = data['FDE Date'].iloc[i]
        d0 = data['FDE Date'].iloc[i-1]
        print(i, d1, d0)
        if d1 - d0 > delta:
            groups.append(groups[-1] + 1)
        else:
            groups.append(groups[-1])
    return groups

# Leemos los datos y los organizamos como queremos
df = pd.read_csv("kk.csv",
                 header=0, 
                 sep=';',
                 parse_dates=[6, 8, 21],
                 date_parser=dateparser)

df['FDE'] = df["Tail #"] +"-"+df["FDE Text"]

# Agrupamos por 'FDE'
groups = df.groupby('FDE')

# Bucle sobre los grupos y extraemos grupos de fechas con la fn agrupa
for group in groups:
    df_tmp = group[1].sort_values('FDE Date')
    group = group[0]
    df_tmp['grupos'] = agrupa(df_tmp)

    # Esto lo tendrás que retocar para extraer la info como consideres
    print("Grupos para ", group)
    print(df_tmp.groupby('grupos')['FDE Date'].count().values)
```

Por partes, `dateparser` es una función que permite leer el csv y transformar las columnas de fechas en fechas. `agrupa` se usa para crear grupos por fechas dentro de cada grupo (ver código). Leemos el fichero y creamos grupos usando `groupby`. Dentro de cada grupo iteramos sobre la columna `FDE Date` para crear una columna de `grupos` que determina si un evento se debe asociar a un grupo o a otro.